# Object attribute in python

Tags: python, object, attributes

I have following in conf1.py file

```
server = { 
  '1':'ABC'
  '2':'CD' 
}

client = {
  '4':'jh'
  '5':'lk' 
}
```

Now in other python file

```
s=__import__('conf1')
temp='server'
for v in conf.temp.keys():
    print v
```

And getting the error that conf object don't have attribute temp
So how can I make this possible to interpret temp as server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = __import__('conf1')
temp = 'server'
for v in getattr(conf, temp): # .keys() not required
    print v
```

Comment: @eldarerathis :Thanks for editing today I also try to learn markdown editing,you can see my new question

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
import conf1

temp=conf1.server 

for v in temp.keys(): print v
```

however you don't need .keys() to iterate over the dict's keys, you can just do:

```
for v in temp: print v
```

Comment: And you don't need `keys()` either. `for v in temp` already iterates over the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a variable named `temp` in the module `conf`. If you want to dynamically get a variable based on a name in a string, use `getattr(conf, temp)` instead of `conf.temp`.